# How to push a development branch to a remote repository after having performed a hard reset?

Tags: git, bitbucket, jira, push, reset

Under Jira, I did create a bitbucket development branch called "RHI-89"

[image]

I wanted this development branch to point three commits behind the master's HEAD.
After running `git fetch` to fetch the newly created branch onto my local machine, I checked out to this development branch and performed a hard rest:

```
git checkout RHI-89
git reset --hard HEAD~3
```

Running `git log` confirmed that the reset worked properly.

However, trying to push to the remote repository returns a "rejected" error, followed by these hints:

> hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is

> behind hint: its remote counterpart. Integrate the remote changes (e.g. hint: 'git pull ...') before pushing again. hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.

I understand what is going on, but I do not know how to fix this issue.
**Is there a way to "prune" the remote development branch so that I can push the local branch without raising any conflict?**

Comment: Has anyone else pulled the remote ahead of where you want to prune?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Nope, I am the only one working on this project at the moment.

Comment: I believe that if you force the push then the remote will end up looking like your local

Comment: It worked! Thanks a lot, @CaiusJard!

Comment: Thanks for your answer, @SwissCodeMen!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are the only one working on this branch RHI-89, in this case, personally I use `git push -f` to push my local reset

Here is the [doc](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-push#Documentation/git-push.txt--f) of the `-f` option

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Ahmed. I actually preferred to push only the development branch to play it safe. I will accept your answer as the `-f` option did the trick.